# Mac terminal - command line being overwritten if line is longer than window

Tags: command-line, terminal

My command line isn't behaving as expected. When I write something that is longer than the window width, the cursor goes back to the beginning of the same line and continues to write on top of the same line instead of automatically moving to the next line. For example, if I write "this is a line to illu" on the command line of my terminal the following is what I see:

```
Last login: Thu Jun 19 18:32:24 on 
e to illu > ~] $ this is a lin
```

Note how the end of the text was being shown at the beginning of the same line. If the terminal window is wide enough I see this:

```
Last login: Thu Jun 19 18:32:24 on 
[MacBook > ~] $ this is a line to illu
```

I'd like it to behave like this:

```
Last login: Thu Jun 19 18:32:24 on 
 [MacBook > ~] $ this is a line to illustrate
 the problem
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: That might not be mac specific: A have observed this on linux, too. Sadly I do not have a solution.

Comment: It's because you're not doing escape sequences in the prompt correctly.

Comment: Unusual but I found the solution. @Barmar, you're right. I customised the colours of my terminal by configuring my PS1. It turned out that I was missing a backslash inside my PS1 quote preceding the color set. My PS1 was:

    PS1="\e[0;30m[\h > \W] \$ \e[m "

resulting in the command lines not wrapping to the next line. I changed to:

    PS1="\\[\e[0;30m[\h > \W] \$ \e[m "

Problem solved!

Comment: You should post it as an answer so it will be readable.

Answer (score 4):

Unusual but I found the solution. @Barmar, you're right. I customised the colours of my terminal by configuring my PS1. It turned out that I was missing a backslash inside my PS1 quote preceding the color set. My PS1 was:

```
PS1="\e[0;30m[\h > \W] \$ \e[m "
```

resulting in the command lines not wrapping to the next line. I changed to:

```
PS1="\\[\e[0;30m[\h > \W] \$ \e[m "
```

Problem solved!